# Brightness Problem Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, screen, brightness, cedarview

I've installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my Asus Eee Netbook. It has a Cedar Trail processor. It has a brightness problem. I can't change the brightness. It is always dimmed. How can I solve this problem ?