# Changing Brightness on netbook

Tags: 12.04, screen, brightness, cedarview

I am using Asus Eee PC R051CX. I am unable to boost up brightnes of my screen. While I was trying ubuntu 12.04 from live img from usb stick it was good, but after installing on local hard disk screen brightness reduced to minimum. I am unable to boost it from screen brightness and lock from ubuntu and from keyboard short cut. Both these are setting at their max. Please help what to do!

Comment: Duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/272017/brightness-problem-ubuntu-12-04

Answer (score 0):

Changing the grup configuration file as mentioned on the link in the comment above should work.  Don't forget sudo update-grub.

Your netbook has the atom 2600/cedarview gma combination like my netbook does.  Frankly the linux support for the graphics isn't good but it runs faster on releases after 12.04.  I run lubuntu 13.10 on mine (though I've also had problems with the broadcom 4313 drivers).  There's a new 14.04 lts coming out soon and that'd be a good choice.

I don't know which version you're using but I wouldn't DREAM of installing ubuntu with the Unity desktop on a 1G netbook with cedarview graphics.  Unity (and others eg Cinnamon) require 3D hardware acceleration.  Try xubuntu or lubuntu.