# Poor performance when opening windows on new PC

Tags: drivers, 13.04, intel-graphics, gma3600

I have just installed Linux on a new PC.

I have a CD of Windows drivers - things seem to run OK, but windows open really slowly (like chug, chug, chug), and menus expand slowly, so presumably it's a graphics driver issue. I am new to everything Linux and have no idea what to do.

Specs are: Intel Atom D2550 Processor, Intel GMA3650 graphics accelerator, Realtek ALC662/661 onboard audio, Dual Broadcom 57788 Gigabit ethernet ports, 8Gb RAM. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I can confirm similar behavior on HP Mini 210-4000. This also has Atom/GMA36xx CPU/GPU combo. Trying to resolve ..

Comment: Likely same issue in: http://askubuntu.com/questions/286884/graphical-bugs-in-unity-nautilus-with-intel-card (unresolved)

Comment: Reverted to **12.04 LTS** for now. Although that gives the 'brightness' bug (http://askubuntu.com/questions/272017/brightness-problem-ubuntu-12-04) and needs third party driver to resolve.

Answer (score 1):

Intel GMA 36xx chipsets are based on PowerVR SGX545. That is, Intel has licensed this chip from Imagination Technologies. I'm not sure the regular open source Intel drivers work with these chipsets, a different one may be provided. The poor performance is mostly due due to the open source driver not supporting 3D acceleration.

If you use Ubuntu 12.04, you might want to try installing the [cedarview-graphics-drivers](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise-updates/cedarview-graphics-drivers) package. I don't know why, it is not available in any other Ubuntu release.

Sorry, just noticed the 13.04 tag... Then unfortunately my answer is irrelevant to you.

Comment: Not at all - I installed 12.04 in place of 13.04 and it seems to have sorted things out to a fairly acceptable degree, so thanks!

Comment: Similar issue currently with Intel **GMA 45xx** chipset as well. So this may not be **CedarTail** related.